# While upgrading Angular from version 5.0 to 6.1, facing npm Error: Unknown argument: serve

Tags: npm

> Error: Unknown argument: serve
>
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
> npm ERR! errno 1
> npm ERR! angular-io-example@1.0.0 start: `ng serve`
> npm ERR! Exit status 1
> npm ERR!
> npm ERR! Failed at the angular-io-example@1.0.0 start script.
> npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

Please provide some solution for this, as I am stuck, not able to run my Angular application.

Answer (score 0):

Encountered the same problem when setting up my development environment on different machine.

Use `npm run serve` instead. It worked to me.